# Find the singularities of $\frac{1}{1-\cos{z}}$ and it's degree

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> Find the singularities of  $$\frac{1}{1-\cos{z}}$$

My attempt: 
$$1-\cos{z} = 0 \iff \cos{z} = 1 \iff z = 2k\pi, k \in Z$$and I would anser that the degree is 1, since we don't have $1-(\cos{z})^2$.

My textbook does indeed state that $z=2k\pi$ is the singularities, but that they have a **degree of 2. Why?**

Comment: What is the Taylor expansion of $1 - \cos z$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Aah obviously, thank you. Just one question though. When I've factored out $z^2$, can I be sure that what's left in the parenthesis does not equal zero?

Comment: Yes. Try putting $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$ into graph.tk (where $x$ is real, of course). Is there any reason why this shouldn't be true when $x$ = $z$ is complex?